# iphone code - change the tabBar badge value from the viewController's

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `UITabBarController`,

How can I create/update the `badge value` of the tabBar item from my `viewController` ?

The `tabBar` item's created in the ib.

I connected the tabBar item to the controller using an `IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar`.

thanks.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If your viewcontroller already has a tab bar controller associate with it, you can just drill down to the tab bar item and set its badge, like this:

```
[[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] 
                   objectAtIndex:tabIndex] setBadgeValue:badgeValueString];
```

where tabIndex is the index of the tab item you want to set and badgeValueString is the string value you want to set on the tab.

Comment: is there a better way to do it, without using a tabIndex? since the view controller was loaded after touching a specific tab bar item, there might be a way...

Answer (score 27):

Use the tabBarItem instance of your view controller to access the tab bar item directly instead of drilling down to it.

```
[self.tabBarItem setBadgeValue:badgeValue];
```

Comment: +1 for simpler solution, Matt's solution works well when updating another tab's badge value, but this solution is easiest when updating the current tabs value.

Comment: Tip: if your view controller is inside a navigation controller, you have to use `[self.navigationController.tabBarItem setBadgeValue:badgeValue];`

Comment: And for those that are looking, here how you remove it '[self.tabBarItem setBadgeValue:nil];'

Answer (score 2):

If there are three tabs in your app `First`, `Second` and `Third`

Tab index starts from 0

```
First  tab index 0
Second tab index 1
Third  tab index 2
```

If you want to set badge value 5 in `Second` tab

So pass 1(tab index of Second tab) for `objectAtIndex:1` and pass 5(badge value) for `setBadgeValue:@"5"`

```
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setBadgeValue:@"5"];
```

Also you can clear/remove badge value passing `nil` for spacific tab

```
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setBadgeValue:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        int indexICareAbout = 2;
        NSString *badgeValue = @"10";

        [[[[[self tabBarController] viewControllers]
        objectAtIndex: indexICareAbout] tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:badgeValue];
```