# How to update default badge UI appearance in UITabbarController?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, badge

[image]

As displayed above, default badge appears in red and white color. Can we change its color scheme and customize that view?

The only solution I found was, creating entire UITabbarController as custom control. Can't I use default control and only update badge or provide custom UI to badge?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949475/iphone-code-change-the-tabbar-badge-value-from-the-viewcontrollers

Comment: @Pradeep: I want to update my badge UI, not its value. For example, instead of red fill color, change it to grey color

Comment: i think you need to create custom layout for that

Comment: This might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22833667/278629

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to create custom badge for `UITabBarItem`. The only way to achieve this is to use custom `UIButton/UIViews.`

Answer (score 0):

You could just create view(`UIButton` for example.) with the color (or background image) and text  you want and add that to the tabbar on the place you want. But I think that would be some kind dirty implementation... Coz, you need to calculate the frame according to how many `UITabbarItem`s you have. Otherwise, custom tabbar controller is the way to go :) I don't think customization of the default badge is possible. Good Luck!